# How to change image in QGraphicsView in PyQT?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I am able show an image initially when the form loads. How can I change the image later with another class.

Main class:

```
self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(Form)
self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 280, 681, 331))
self.graphicsView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("graphicsView"))
self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(search_result)) 
self.graphicsView.setScene(ui.scene)
```

another class:

```
ui.graphicsView.resetCachedContent()
ui.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('path to another file')) 
ui.graphicsView.setScene(ui.scene)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jpg images can't be displayed in QGraphicsView.
use QLabel to show jpg images